# Visio: Anchor to Sloping Face of Diamond Shape?

Tags: ms-office, diagram, visio, anchorpoint, visio2013

In Visio one of the most fundamental and frustrating annoyances I'm facing is not being able to anchor to the sloping face of the diamond shape.

My organization commonly uses this shape in flow diagrams.

Whether it's a densely connected logic point, which needs more than the 5-6 anchors...

[image: Another Visio diamond example]

...or a self connecting loop like this:

[image: Visio Diamond]

...I often want to connect to the sloping faces of the diamond shape, but can't seem to find a way to successfully anchor to the sloping part of the shape.

Currently I'm settling for connecting one side, but that leads to frustration when things are repositioned.

I've also explored the `Data` and `Format Shape` menus presented by right clicking the shape and the path I'm looking to connect to it as those sounded promising.  However, examining those menus, I haven't found anything that looks close to what I need yet.

Seems like there must be a way to do this, though.

---

### Update

I've also tried to redraw the diamond w/ a `Pencil` in the ribbon's `Tools` pane under the `Shapes` dropdown ... but did not have any luck anchoring to the result.

I also have clarified that my question is relating to a basic anchoring need, given my initial example's deviation from traditional UML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Overview

To anchor to somewhere on a shape face other than the defaults, simply add connector points. (`Shift`+`Ctrl`+`1`, by default)

If this is a common issue, create a master shape with additional connection points to reduce time cost.

---

### Adding Connectors

In **Visio 2010** or later:

1.) Enabling `Connection Points`

Under `Views` tab, be sure `Connection Points` in `Visual Aids` group is CHECKED:

[image: Connection Points is checked]

**!!** NOTE: If this step is ignored, attempts to add points may fail.

2.) Enter Connection Point Edit Mode

Either enter press `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `1` or go to `Tools` group in `Home` tab and click the `x` (`Connection Point`) to enter appropriate edit mode.

[image: Enter appropriate mode to edit]

3.) Select Shape

Click to select the shape to be edited.

4.) Add a point

Hold `Ctrl` and then click again on the desired position along the face of the selected shape to add a point.

(`Visio 2013` -- after adding a point)
[image: Point added]

The point is depicted in `Visio 2010` as a magenta 'x', while it's depicted as a red square in `Visio 2013`.  The shape itself is thinly outlined, w/ pre-existing connection points shown as blue 'x's in `Visio 2010`; for `Visio 2013`, it's instead depicted as a gray bounding box, w/ pre-existing points show in gray for unselected shapes.

You must select the shape before adding the points, however, once selected as many points as are desired may be added.

BEWARE -- once a shape has been selected, you can add connections on other shapes nearby, as well, leading to potentially weird routing.

Complete!
[image: Completed]

Comment: Got it working, but there's a couple of tricks I had to figure out to get it.  Is it okay if I edit this post to include pictures and additional text to explain this?  Or would you prefer I post my own solution w/ those additional details, citing you?

Comment: @JasonR.Mick: Happy for you to edit with your pictures and additional explanations. Will always help future users.

Comment: Done @AJD, please see text & picture revisions / additions to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind: you are not asking a UML, but a Visio drawing question.

However, I answer in UML context: your drawing does not make sense. Removing the `No` path will just make it a more valid one. Then it should be an `Action` called `Wait for something` that continues only when a `something` happens. You take a decision only if there's something to decide, not to stop the control flow until an event happens.

[image]

---

In response to your chat question (use of UML): Everything depends. Whether or not you stick with the UML specification (actually the ISO source is available for free at the [author's site](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/)) is your decision. UML itself leaves great ways to adapt the language to your domain by using profiles. Whenever you deviate from the standard you have to document that and people need to be trained accordingly.

I have to admit that the UML specification is no bedtime lecture. However, there are great sources to learn from (e.g. lots of examples are found [here](https://www.uml-diagrams.org)). I for myself work with UML in practice for more than 20 years and have to say that it was worth the time learning it. Always remember that UML is a **language** and like any language it needs to be spoken actively to convey ideas effectively. Here in Germany we have so many dialects and a general High German. People with a certain idiom can talk to each of their peers without issue, but people from north and south are better served to use the common idiom since their own dialects differ quite fundamentally.

Comment: I can remove the "UML" to make it clear this is a somewhat localized convention that employs shorthands such as not explicitly depicting a "waiting" action, but infers it from a self-reference path on logic symbol.

But my question is a more fundamental one -- how do you connect to the side of a shape w/ a sloping face.  I'll upload an additional example that would probably be considered standard UML.

Comment: As I said: if you ask a Visio drawing question, remove the UML tag. I just answer the UML part (which is wrong in your drawing).

Comment: See updated question.  I apologize for the erroneous usage of "UML" relative my initial example, and appreciate you helping me fix that. Hopefully you'll consider submitting an answer to my post per its intent, now that I've updated to clarify this is a general diagram and have included a case applicable to standard UML.

Comment: Ok. I will remove my answer (though I think you should try to improve your modeling skills). Cheers.

Comment: Sounds good... I opened a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164373/discussion-of-official-uml

Hopefully you can chime in there and give me more info so I can follow your advice.  Thanks!

Comment: Those chat rooms are wadis. You don't get notified. So I posted my answer to your question above.